# How to fix broken relative links in offline webpages?

Tags: python, html, hyperlink, offline-browsing

I wrote a simple Python script to download a web page for offline viewing.  The problem is that the relative links are broken.  So the offline file "c:\temp\webpage.html" has a href="index.aspx" but when opened in a browser it resolves to "file:///C:/temp/index.aspx" instead of "http://myorginalwebsite.com/index.aspx".

So I imagine that I would have to modify my script to fix each of the relative links so that it points to the original website.  Is there an easier way?  If not, anyone have some sample Python code that can do this?  I'm a Python newbie so any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: an easier way: `wget -rkw 2 example.com`

Comment: @The MYYN: Great point - wget can already do this. However, reinventing the wheel is quite desirable *if you plan to learn how wheels work*.

Comment: @Piskvor: Certainly. Learning about the wheels is most enlightening.

Comment: @Piskvor, not inherently. If you do this from scratch, how do you magically learn how `wget` works? How do you know that the way you're doing works in all cases or is the idiomatic way to approach the problem?

Comment: @Aaron Gallagher: Doing it from scratch doesn't mean blinding oneself to how others do it, right? In other words, "I can also do this with wget" is not the end of it, but another possible avenue of exploration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want your relative links to refer to the website, just add a base tag in the head:

```
<base href="http://myoriginalwebsite.com/" />
```

Comment: Okay, now, how do you add this to the page in the context of the question?

Comment: The base tag just needs to be added to the head tag of the local file. 
Actually, for pretty much all browsers, it doesn't have to be in the head tag, it can just be the first element in the page.
I don't know python, so I don't know specifically how that would be done, but basically, just prepend the base tag to the downloaded HTML.

Comment: This does exactly what I need.  I have to figure out how to add that to the file.  Can't be too hard...

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way but I simply used Python replace() to change the HTML file so that <HEAD> becomes <HEAD> <base href="http://myoriginalwebsite.com/" />

That works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

[lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) makes this braindead simple!

```
>>> import lxml.html, urllib
>>> url = 'http://www.google.com/'
>>> e = lxml.html.parse(urllib.urlopen(url))
>>> e.xpath('//a/@href')[-4:]
['/intl/en/ads/', '/services/', '/intl/en/about.html', '/intl/en/privacy.html']
>>> e.getroot().make_links_absolute()
>>> e.xpath('//a/@href')[-4:]
['http://www.google.com/intl/en/ads/', 'http://www.google.com/services/', 'http://www.google.com/intl/en/about.html', 'http://www.google.com/intl/en/privacy.html']
```

From there you can write the DOM out to disk as a file.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to check all links that start with `http://` but any that don't you want to append `http://myoriginalwebsite.com` to the front of the string, then test for connection?

Sounds easy enough. Or is it the python code proper you're having issues with?

Comment: Caveat: if the link starts with `?`, you need to prepend the path and file also; and if it doesn't start with `/`, prepend path.

Comment: @piskvor ~ good point. I was really looking for problem clarification. I took it he wanted to scrape static files looking for links, not modify existing files. C'est la vie I suppose. Too much to ask some questioners about their problem domain some days...